# Python - ignore empty cells in len() with csv.DictReader

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary, cells

I stumbled across problem while comparing rows in CSV files.

I could use csv.reader with len() and it works just fine, but I then I have to sort the file on the key.

I have unique keys so I want to use DictReader but len() seems to read all values in dict including empty cells:

```
with open (baseline, 'r') as baselineF:
     readBaseline=csv.DictReader(baselineF, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')        


                        for rowb in readBaseline:

                            print('rowb: ',len(rowb))

                            with open (tested, 'r') as testedF:
                                 readTested=csv.DictReader(testedF, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

                            for rowt in readTested:

                                print ('rowt: ', len(rowt))


                                # Rows are the same len
                                if len(rowb)==len(rowt):                                        
                                    writerSameOracle.writerow(rowb)
                                    writerSameHPCC.writerow(rowt)
                                    print ('Rows are the same')
                                    break
```

With this code even if rows have the same number of populated cells it seems to return len() = to number of headers in each file.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing seems a bit confusing but it's trivial to filter out anything that is falsey:

```
>>> rowb = [1,2,0,3]
# using list comprehension
>>> len([x for x in rowb if x])
3
# alternatively using filter in Python 2
>>> len(filter(None, rowb))
3
```

Comment: Neither of them worked:

**1.** len(filter(bool, rowb)
    print('\nrowb: ',len(filter(bool, rowb)))
TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()

**2.** print('\nrowb: ',len([x for x in rowb if x != None])) would always produce lan=to number of keys/headers

@2rs2ts

Comment: It's extremely hard to read your code in a comment; either write it such that the program can be read in one line or edit your question to include how you have changed your code based on my answer. Anyway, both of these work, so you are doing something wrong. Perhaps you have shadowed `filter`. Perhaps you did not want to use `x != None` but rather just the truthiness of `x` as I had recommended. Perhaps you are not using the length of the filtered list correctly. You should provide example inputs and the expected output (compared to the actual output.)

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I forgot that `filter()` has its own return type now in Python 3. I still use Python 2. Let me adjust my answer.

Comment: rowb is a Dict not a List so I do not know if comprehension would work. Probably not? @2rs2ts

Comment: You would simply use `rowb.values()` instead then.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to load values for dict to list and then count len(). Based on this use appropriate if statement to do the job.

```
with open (baseline, 'r') as baselineF:
                        readBaseline=csv.DictReader(baselineF,delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for rowb in readBaseline:


                            with open (tested, 'r') as testedF:
                                readTested=csv.DictReader(testedF, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')


                                for rowt in readTested:                                       

                                    if rowt['key'] == rowb['key']:                                   

                                        for value in rowb.values():

                                            list1.append(value)
                                            cleaned1 = [x for x in list1 if x != None]

                                        list1=[]                                                 


                                        for value in rowt.values():

                                            list2.append(value)
                                            cleaned2 = [x for x in list2 if x != None]

                                        list1=[]     

                                        #rowb baseline
                                        #rowt tested


                                        #Rows are the same len
                                        if len(cleaned1)==len(cleaned2):                                        
                                            writerSameOracle.writerow(rowb)
                                            writerSameHPCC.writerow(rowt)
                                            print ('Rows are the same)
                                            break
```